# Problem getting parameter value in Android

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the async key, it didn't get the parameter that arrives in the onCreate method. Do you know maybe what the problem is?
Problem getting parameter value in Android
Code is below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_unos);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        context = this;
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        username = extras.getString("username");
        password = extras.getString("password");
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        voznja = (Voznja) intent.getSerializableExtra("voznja");
        voznjaId = voznja.getId();
        System.out.println(voznjaId);//it works here




public class Home extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                    .build();
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("text/plain");
            RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
                    .add("voznja_id", voznja.getId())//but i get null here, dont know why//
                    .build();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("http://www.autotrack.rs/android_juzna_backa/get_voznja.php?")
                    .method("POST", body)
                    .build();
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
//                System.out.println(response.body().string());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "";
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String unused) {
            try {
                String rezultat = response.body().string();
                //System.out.println(rezultat);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Type type = new TypeToken<Data>() {
                }.getType();
                Data data = gson.fromJson(rezultat, type);
                // System.out.println(model);//
                //listaVoznjiAL.add(data.data);
                //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Intent i = new Intent(Unos.this, Landing.class);
                i.putExtra("data",data);
                i.putExtra("voznja", voznja);
                i.putExtra("username", username);
                i.putExtra("password", password);
                startActivity(i);
            } catch (Exception m) {
                m.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

> ERROR:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified
> as non-null is null: method
> kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your AsyncTask is executing before onCreate.

Where are you calling AsyncTask?

Comment: I call asynctask in bottom navigation view like this: new ClassName.Home().Execute();

Comment: Ok... do it like this:
At the beginning of the donInBackground function (it's in AsyncTask) add the line
`
System.out.println("doInBackground is start execute");
`

And at the beginning of the onCreate function add
`
System.out.println("onCreate is start execute");
`

Run it and tell me what will be displayed first. I think at the beginning it will print "doInBackground is start execute"

Comment: I/System.out: onCreate is start execute

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have Discord: RAGNAROS#8729

Comment: I will add you now.